# Completely transparent UIButton with irregular hit area

Tags: uibutton, hittest, alpha-transparency

I know how to use a background image with alpha channel to create a `UIButton` with an irregular tap area. But with this solution, only the ignore-tap area is transparent; the tap area consists of the *opaque*.

What I want is a *totally* transparent `UIButton`, with an irregular tap area. (It triggers an animation behind the button.)

It seems that some sort of extra `UILayer` with some hit-testing could work, but I don't quite see how. Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. The problem: A `UIImageView` (call it the **base view**) to which I want to attach an irregularly-shaped tap area. The area corresponds to something in the image, let's call it a river. It could be a non-connected region.

In the Finder, duplicate the view's image, and make all the non-river pixels transparent, using your favorite graphics app. Call this the **mask image**.

When the base view is tapped, check to see if the *corresponding* pixel in the mask image is or is not transparent. (Solution left to reader; examples abound.)

So the mask image is never actually rendered, it is just used as a reference.

Note that if the base view gets resized or moved around (as it does in my app, via animating its constraints) then you have to "move" the mask image too, or in some other way manage the coordinate translation between view and mask. The easiest way to do this is to make the mask image a *hidden* subview of the base view, with its left, top, leading and trailing anchors constrained to be equal to those of the base view. Then they move around together, and the coord translation between the two is the identity.

I wrapped all this up in a subclass of `UIImageView` so that it manages its own mask, and calls a delegate if the "river" (or whatever) is tapped.